# Joomla 2 - Error moving file when upload

Tags: joomla, upload

I'm writing a plugin, i used function `JFile:upload($src, $dest)` to upload image file to host. T setting up temp directory to "tmp". But i got a error "Failed to move file".

I try to set up permission "tmp" directory to 777, but it not change.

In Configuration->Directory Permission, status of "tmp" directory is also "unwritable".

How i could solved this problem?

```
   $fileTemp = $_FILES[$fieldName]['tmp_name'];
   $fileName = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/i", ".", $fileName);

   $uploadPath = JPATH_SITE.DS.'images'.DS.$fileName;

   if(!JFile::upload($fileTemp, $uploadPath)) 
    {
     $article->setError(JText::_( 'ERROR MOVING FILE' ));
     JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(JText::_( 'ERROR MOVING FILE'));
     return false;
    }
```

Comment: unless the folder is writable, it won't work as it is moving the file to the `tmp` folder first and then to the specified location. Try changing the permissions to 755 as sometimes servers don't like 777. Also, try using Admin Tools which is an extensions that provides a features to set all file and folder permissions.
files should be **644** and folders should be **755**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Joomla tmp folder, it's set in `configuration.php` or in `administrator->configuration` I guess you have it pointing to tmp instead of `/home/something/public_html/tmp`